# VSTO Signed, but still get confirm prompt at install

Tags: vsto, code-signing

I develop a VSTO addon for Outlook. I sign the addon with a certificate purchased with Verisign Inc. The cert is valid and authorized by a trusted root authority. But when my customers install the addon they are still prompted with "Do you want to install this addon from this publisher?" question.

From what I understand Verisign cert is enough to make this go away, am I right?
Is this prompt a mandatory in VSTO addon installation?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the prompt isn't mandatory, but it sounds like either
1) your code isn't actually signed, even though you think it is (you should be able to verify that by right clicking on the compiled DLL and examining the security tab)
2) The Cert isn't the right kind of cert (there are different kinds of certs, I believe the one you need is called a "Code Signing" cert.
3) Maybe there's an older version on the customer's machine that's still being loaded (and hence prompting)?

But short answer is, with the right cert, properly signed and properly installed, the user won't get the prompt.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out that the build machine needs to have the cert installed properly in order to make the prompt disappear.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I had a similar prob when I was getting automated builds setup with TFS and Build Server. You can do some amazing things with build server by manually editing the visual studio *PROJ files to add build targets and steps that are executed when build on the build server, but are ignored when compiled locally by your devs. It's really slick because it keeps all your build logic right there in the proj and solution files. But that's a whole other story